# Laravel Blade Include

Tags: php, laravel

Появилась необходимость динамически инклудить файлы, как можно заставить работать данный код в Laravel?

```
@include('template.information_page' . $row->template_path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё работает. Вот:

Шаблон:

```
<body>
   @include('random'.$data['randomBlade']);
</body>
```

Контроллер:

```
class HomeController extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'randomBlade' => rand(0, 2)
        ];
        return view('pages.messages.index')
                ->withData($data);
    }
}
```

random0.blade.php:

```
<h1>random0</h1>
```

random1.blade.php:

```
<h1>random1</h1>
```

random2.blade.php:

```
<h1>random2</h1>
```